# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'slice')

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm really struggling to work out what's wrong with my code below in Google Sheets.
I've defined my data globally above all my functions, but I'm still getting the dreaded error of uncaught TypeError and I can't work out where to go from here to be able to get the data from the getDataForSearch function into the results array.

Code is as per below from a page called main.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ComplyNZ BCO Training Log</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
      .nav-link {
        cursor:pointer;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <div class="nav-link active" id="homeLink">Home</div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <div class="nav-link" id="searchLink">Search</div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <div class="nav-link" id="addEntryLink">Add Entry</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div id="app"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>

      var data;

      function loadView(options) {
        var id = typeof options.id === "undefined" ? "app" : options.id;
        var cb = typeof options.callback === "undefined" ? function() {} : options.callback;
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(html) {
          document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html;
          typeof options.params === "undefined" ? cb() : cb(options.params);
        })[options.func]();
      }

      function setDataForSearch() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(dataReturned) {
          data = dataReturned.slice();
        }).getDataForSearch();
      }

      function search() {
        var searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
        var resultsArray = data.filter(function(r) {
          return r[1].indexOf(searchInput) !== -1;
        });
        var searchResultsBox = document.getElementById("searchResults");
        var templateBox = document.getElementById("rowTemplate");
        var template = templateBox.content;
        resultsArray.forEach(function(r) {
          var tr = template.cloneNode(true);
          var entryIDColumn = tr.querySelector(".entryID");
          var trainingTopicColumn = tr.querySelector(".trainingTopic");
          var dateUndertakenColumn = tr.querySelector(".dateUndertaken");
          entryIDColumn.textContent = r[0];
          trainingTopicColumn.textContent = r[1];
          dateUndertakenColumn.textContent = r[2];
          searchResultsBox.appendChild(tr);
        })
      }

      function loadSearchView() {
        loadView({func:"loadSearchView", callback: setDataForSearch});
      }

      function loadAddEntryView() {
        loadView({func:"loadAddEntryView"});
      }

      function loadEditEntryView() {
        loadView({func:"loadEditEntryView"});
      }

      function inputEventHandler(e) {
        if(e.target.match("#searchInput")) {
          search();
        }
      }

      document.getElementById("searchLink").addEventListener("click",loadSearchView);
      document.getElementById("addEntryLink").addEventListener("click",loadAddEntryView);
      document.getElementById("homeLink").addEventListener("click",loadEditEntryView);
      document.getElementById("app").addEventListener("input",inputEventHandler);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code from another script page called serverSideFunctions as follows:

```
function getDataForSearch() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Training Log");
  return ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The error says that `dataReturned` is null.

Comment: But on a different note, `setDataForSearch` doesn't get called anywhere in the code you're showing. Also, if you're showing three separate blocks of code, either add guide text in your post that explains what each block is and where it's coming from, or show a single block of code, ideally in [mcve] form.

Comment: Can you show a log of `dataReturned`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've updated the section of code to show the full code as recommended

Comment: The error is telling you that `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler` is calling your `function (dataReturned) {}` with `null`, so you probably want to look up what the call signature for functions passed into `withSuccessHandler` is supposed to be. I've not used google scripts, but I assume `null` means "the code _ran_ but didn't _result_ in anything".